# How can I update increment two fields in one command in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The documentation tells me this is legal if I want to set one value and increment another:

```
{ $set : { x : 1 }, $inc : { y : 1 } }
```

What if I want increment both variables? I'm trying this but it isn't working:

```
{ $inc : [{ y : 1 }, { x : 1 }] }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm an idiot:

`{ $inc : { y : 1, x : 1 } }`